# Struts 2 ajax sx:div refresh not working after upgrade

Tags: ajax, struts2, refresh

I recently upgraded from Struts 2.0.11 to the latest version (2.3.15) and have found that I can not get an *sx:div* tag to refresh. This is the code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" %>
<sx:head debug="true" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var controller = {
    refresh : function() {}
};

dojo.event.topic.registerPublisher("/refresh", controller, "refresh");
</script>

<s:url id="URLAjaxKaptcha" namespace="%{#attr.kaptchaNamespace}" action="kaptcha"/>
<sx:div  id="prosoc_kaptcha" theme="ajax" href="%{URLAjaxKaptcha}"
         loadingText="<small>loading &#133;</small>"
         errorText="Security code is loading - please wait"
         listenTopics="/refresh" cssClass="kaptchaDiv">

</sx:div>

<s:a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="controller.refresh()">click to get a new image</s:a>.
```

Before the upgrade, when the user clicked the refresh hyperlink a new kaptcha image was returned to the *sx:div*. After the upgrade this doesn't work any more.

I am not getting any error messages and I can place an alert in a *beforeNotifyTopics* and *afterNotifyTopics* so I know that the refresh function is being called. I just don't get a new kaptcha image in the *sx:div*.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: In the download there is a struts2-dojo-plugin.jar file and the apps download comes with many examples of ajax integration for Struts-2.3.15. I also load the kaptcha via the dojo plugin. That would seem to go against your claim. Is there another alternative?

Comment: :) The Struts2 dojo plugin is deprecated.

Comment: It appears you are correct: http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/FAQ . Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16987761/1654265